# Script to browse to "Temporary Internet Files" folder

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, shell, wininet

I just want to be able to remove some specific files in my temporary internet files folder (for Internet Explorer), however I know that this is a *special* folder, and it doesn't seem to be straight-forward. Do I need to use the Shell object and reference WinINET? Was planning on doing this in C# or VB. Something simple. Any input is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to write a script that opens an Explorer window showing the Temporary Internet Files folder, or a program that automatically deletes specific entries from that folder?